# Error pulling edgeAgent from ACR with Windows container on IoT Edge v1.1

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am working with a customer using the v1.1 of IoT Edge with Windows containers.  They are in a locked down environment and do not want to connect to a public container registry.  They prefer to ingest from their own Azure Container Registry (ACR).  We have copied edgeAgent and edgeHub from our public registry to ACR using `az acr import` to pull the containers from:

- mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.1
- mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.1

I am finding that Azure IoT Edge cannot download the edgeAgent image.  If I download the edgeAgent container manually from ACR, edgeAgent will start will start correctly.  edgeAgent will also be able to download and install edgeHub via ACR.  eg.:

```
docker -H "npipe:////./pipe/iotedge_moby_engine" pull <private ACR>.azurecr.io/azureiotedge-agent:1.1
```

Any thoughts on why IoT Edge is unable to pull the image itself?  Is there something wrong with my config.yaml configuration for edgeAgent?

```
agent:
  name: "edgeAgent"
  type: "docker"
  env: {}
  config:
    image: "<private ACR>.azurecr.io/azureiotedge-agent:1.1"
    auth:
      username: "<username>"
      password: "<key>"
      serveraddress: "<address>.azurecr.io"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow-nondistributable-artifacts` may be required. Please see

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#allow-push-of-nondistributable-artifacts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/faq#how-do-i-make-my-container-images-available-on-air-gapped-machines

Note this setting is required on the docker daemon *pushing* the public images to the private registry, not the IoT Edge device itself.

If that doesn't help, I'd suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/azure/iotedge/issues and be sure to include logs from the iotedged service.

Comment: Thanks Venkat, I will give that a try.  Note that IoT Edge is able to download edgeHub once edgeAgent is manually downloaded.  Wouldn't allow-nondistributable-artifacts cause an issue for edgeHub as well?

Comment: Is there a way to better protect the ACR credentials?  My customer does not want to put them in open text in config.yaml.  For example, is there a way to set them using environment variables?

Comment: The only way currently is using scoped credentials (e.g. read only) for container registry using service principals or tokens. You could also try pre-loading the bootstrap edgeAgent image using 'docker import'.